# Using AJAX to pass variable from dynamic html table to php updating query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to add a value in the input text `valor` and assign this value to the row where it is, for this I need pass to the update query `ID`  and the `valor`.

What am I doing wrong?

> Table

```
<?php
$IDTipoEquipamento = $_POST['Car'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tipocaracteristicas.IDTipoCaracteristicas,tipoequipamento.TipoEquipamento, caracteristicas.Caracteristica, Valor FROM `tipocaracteristicas` LEFT JOIN tipoequipamento on tipoequipamento.IDTipoEquipamento= tipocaracteristicas.IDTipoEquipamento LEFT JOIN caracteristicas on caracteristicas.IDCaracteristicas=tipocaracteristicas.IDCaraterisiticas  WHERE tipocaracteristicas.IDTipoEquipamento= '$IDTipoEquipamento';");
echo "<table width='100% class='sortable' id='datatables-example'>
    <tr>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='pure-table'></td>
        <td class='pure-table'><b>Tipo de Equipamento</b></td>
        <td class='pure-table'><b>Caracteristica</b></td>
        <td class='pure-table'><b>Valor</b></td>
        <td class='pure-table'><b>Atribuir</b></td>
    </tr>";  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='IDTipoCaracteristicas' id='IDTipoCaracteristicas' value='". $row['IDTipoCaracteristicas'] . "'></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['TipoEquipamento'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Caracteristica'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='valor' id='valor' value=''></td>";
echo "<td><a href='' onclick='UpdateTable()'><img id='img' src='save_icon.gif'/></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";    
}
echo"<br>";
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

> Jquery + Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateTable() {

         $("#valor").on('input', function() {
            var valor = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
            url: 'insertCharacteristicsEquipment.php',
            type: "POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{valor:valor},
            async: false,
            dataType:'html',
            success:function(data) {
                 $("#valor").html(data); 
                  alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });

          $("#IDTipoCaracteristicas").on('input', function(){
            var IDTipoCaracteristicas = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            url: 'insertCharacteristicsEquipment.php',
            type: "POST",
            cache:false,
            data:{IDTipoCaracteristicas:IDTipoCaracteristicas},
            async: false,
            dataType:'html',
            success:function(data) {
                  $("#IDTipoCaracteristicas").html(data);
                  alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        });
    }
</script>
```

> PHP UPDATE QUERY PAGE

```
<?php
include ('conetar.php');
if(isset($_POST['valor'], $_POST['IDTipoCaracteristicas'])){
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
    $IDTipoCaracteristicas= $_POST['IDTipoCaracteristicas'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `tipocaracteristicas` SET `Valor`='$valor' WHERE `IDTipoCaracteristicas`= '$IDTipoCaracteristicas'";
   if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){  
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. ";
}  
    mysqli_close($conn)
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem here

Comment: what error you get?? also you are using oninput event to make ajax which might be causing error as at each keystroke an ajax request is sent..and your server might not be able to handle that..try using onChange/onfouseout

Comment: There's a bunch of code with no proper explanation of *what is not working*, *what is the expected output* etc. Kindly explain your problem clearly.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul The expected output is to see in mysql the updated value. Something that does not happen

Comment: @RohitS don't does the update.I want just when i click execute the jquery function

Comment: @djva I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @djva you have used oninput event in your code which is fired as you input value within control and according to your expectation it was supposed to be placed outside your update updateTable function or you could have used val() function within UpdateTable function..which is recommended by Rajdeep now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below two statements here,

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='IDTipoCaracteristicas' id='IDTipoCaracteristicas' value='". $row['IDTipoCaracteristicas'] . "'></td>";
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
echo "<td><input type='text' name='valor' id='valor' value=''></td>";
                                          ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
```

You're assigning the same *id* for all of your table rows, use *class* instead. Assign *class* to each of your *IDTipoCaracteristicas*, *Valor* input elements as well as to the *update table* hyperlinks. Furthermore, you didn't assign any value in *Valor* input element. Also, make the anchor tags non-linkable using `javascript:void(0);`, otherwise you'll get redirected every time you click on a link. So your `while()` loop should be like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='IDTipoCaracteristicas' class='IDTipoCaracteristicas' value='". $row['IDTipoCaracteristicas'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['TipoEquipamento'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Caracteristica'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='valor' class='valor' value='". $row['Valor'] ."'></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='updateTable'><img id='img' src='save_icon.gif'/></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";    
}
```

Subsequently, your jQuery/AJAX code should be like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.updateTable', function(){
            var IDTipoCaracteristicas = $(this).parents('tr').find('.IDTipoCaracteristicas').val();
            var valor = $(this).parents('tr').find('.valor').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'insertCharacteristicsEquipment.php',
                type: "POST",
                cache:false,
                data:{valor:valor, IDTipoCaracteristicas: IDTipoCaracteristicas},
                async: false,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If i change the value of the input text `Valor`, the function `onclick='UpdateTable(". $row['IDTipoCaracteristicas'] .", ". $row['Valor'] .")` ,  doesn't pass the value of `. $row['Valor'] .` changed..

Comment: @djva That's because either of them or both the column values are of string type. What's the datatype of *Valor* and *IDTipoCaracteristicas* columns. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The datatype of IDTipoCaracteristicas is numeric and valor are varchar. The problem is not IDTipoCaracteristicas, is Valor because if i force a value from Valor, it works.

Comment: @djva I've completely updated my answer. Please test your application with the updated PHP and jQuery/AJAX code snippets.